# how can i save Transactions and get the Transactions back when i reload my page?

Tags: system, currency, transfer

in this code i want to save the Transactions and get the Transactions back when i reload my page so that the records will stay there forever. but it seems its not working that way. i dont want to do any server side work. i want all the code on one same page. anyone who want to help me . have to fix the full code for me cuz i am new to this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Money Transfer System</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="profile" id="user1">
    <h2>User 1</h2>
    <p>Balance: $<span class="balance">100</span></p>
    <input type="number" class="amount" placeholder="Enter amount">
    <input type="text" class="receiver" placeholder="Receiver username">
    <button onclick="sendAmount(1)">Send Money</button>
    <h3>Transaction Records</h3>
    <ul class="transactionRecords"></ul>
  </div>

  <div class="profile" id="user2">
    <h2>User 2</h2>
    <p>Balance: $<span class="balance">150</span></p>
    <input type="number" class="amount" placeholder="Enter amount">
    <input type="text" class="receiver" placeholder="Receiver username">
    <button onclick="sendAmount(2)">Send Money</button>
    <h3>Transaction Records</h3>
    <ul class="transactionRecords"></ul>
  </div>


  <script>
      function sendAmount(sender) {
  let parentProfile = document.getElementById('user' + sender);
  let amount = parseFloat(parentProfile.getElementsByClassName('amount')[0].value);
  let receiver = parentProfile.getElementsByClassName('receiver')[0].value;
  let balanceElement = parentProfile.getElementsByClassName('balance')[0];
  let balance = parseFloat(balanceElement.textContent);

  if (receiver !== "user" + sender) { // Prevent sending to oneself
    if (amount > 0 && amount <= balance) {
      // Validate the receiver's username
      if (receiver === "user1" || receiver === "user2") {
        // Deduct the amount from sender's balance
        balance -= amount;
        balanceElement.textContent = balance;

        // Update sent records for the sender with date and time
        let sentRecords = parentProfile.getElementsByClassName('transactionRecords')[0];
        let sentRecord = document.createElement('li');
        let currentDate = new Date().toLocaleString(); // Get the current date and time
        sentRecord.textContent = `Sent $${amount} to ${receiver} - ${currentDate}`;
        sentRecords.appendChild(sentRecord);

        // Update received records for the receiver with date and time
        let receiverProfile = document.getElementById('user' + (receiver === "user1" ? 1 : 2));
        let receiverBalanceElement = receiverProfile.getElementsByClassName('balance')[0];
        let receiverBalance = parseFloat(receiverBalanceElement.textContent);
        receiverBalance += amount;
        receiverBalanceElement.textContent = receiverBalance;

        let receivedRecords = receiverProfile.getElementsByClassName('transactionRecords')[0];
        let receivedRecord = document.createElement('li');
        receivedRecord.textContent = `Received $${amount} from User ${sender} - ${currentDate}`;
        receivedRecords.appendChild(receivedRecord);
      } else {
        alert("Invalid receiver username. Please enter 'user1' or 'user2'.");
      }
    } else {
      alert("Invalid amount or insufficient balance");
    }
  } else {
    alert("You cannot send money to yourself.");
  }


   // After updating the transaction records, save the transaction to transaction.txt
      saveTransactionToTxt(sentRecord.textContent); // save the transaction details to file
    }

    function retrieveTransactions() {
      fetch('transaction.txt')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
          // Parse the data and populate transaction records
          // Example:
          // let transactionRecords = data.split('\n');
          // transactionRecords.forEach(record => {
          //   // Populate transaction records in the respective user profiles
          // });
        })
    }

    function saveTransactionToTxt(transactionDetails) {
      fetch('saveTransaction.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ transaction: transactionDetails })
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          // Transaction details saved successfully
        } else {
          // Handle error
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle error
      });
    }

    // Call retrieveTransactions when the page loads to populate transaction records
    window.onload = retrieveTransactions;
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function sendAmount(sender) {
     // After updating the transaction records, save the transaction to localStorage
    saveTransactionToLocalStorage(sender, sentRecord.textContent);
    saveTransactionToLocalStorage(receiver === "user1" ? 2 : 1, receivedRecord.textContent);
  }

  function saveTransactionToLocalStorage(user, transactionDetails) {
    let transactions = localStorage.getItem('transactions_user' + user);
    transactions = transactions ? JSON.parse(transactions) : [];
    transactions.push(transactionDetails);
    localStorage.setItem('transactions_user' + user, JSON.stringify(transactions));
  }

  function loadTransactions() {
    for (let user = 1; user <= 2; user++) {
      let transactions = localStorage.getItem('transactions_user' + user);
      if (transactions) {
        transactions = JSON.parse(transactions);
        let transactionList = document.getElementById('user' + user).getElementsByClassName('transactionRecords')[0];
        transactions.forEach(transaction => {
          let listItem = document.createElement('li');
          listItem.textContent = transaction;
          transactionList.appendChild(listItem);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // Call loadTransactions when the page loads to populate transaction records
  window.onload = loadTransactions;
</script>
```

`saveTransactionToLocalStorage` function saves each transaction in localStorage. It keeps an array of transactions for each user.

`loadTransactions` function is called when the page loads. It retrieves the stored transactions from localStorage and populates the transaction records for each user.